# В каких случаях нужно использовать расширения процессора типа SSE?

Tags: ассемблер, расширения

Например, создаётся 3D игра с физикой.
Проанализировали CPUID, получили информацию о расширениях.
Дальше, где их использовать? В любых вычислениях? Или в самых критичных?
Может быть для работы с матрицами?
И ведь этих SSE много разных, и не только SSE.
Что, где, для чего их лучше использовать?
Нельзя же их оставлять в нерабочим состоянии?

Comment: ответ на вопрос "где их использовать" - профайлер! Анализировать cpuid, что бы решить, какое sse использовать.... если мы говорит о sse, а не о sse2, sse3, то скорее всего у геймеров даже компа такого не будет, что бы его не поддерживал:)

Comment: Уверен что найти копм без sse2/sse3 будет не легче, особенно у геймеров.

Comment: Суть вопроса не в этом.

Comment: Использовать в тех случаях, когда это a) возможно, b) оправданно. Можно перейти с ассемблера на C++. Современные компиляторы на всю катушку используют все возможности процессоров.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ будет точно таким же, как и для любых оптимизаций: берется профайлер, ищутся узкие места в программе, применяется та или иная методика оптимизации (в вашем случае - SSE), проверяется, есть ли улучшение, и стоит ли овчинка выделки (см. [закон Амдала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0)).

Да, ответ не слишком конкретный, но вряд ли на такой общий вопрос можно дать более конкретный ответ...